# Lodash - replace object in array with the same index

Tags: javascript, lodash

I want to replace the object with the same ID in an array. I have used .unionBy using Lodash. The problem is the the new object appears at the the first instead of the same index.

Here is my code. Hope you can help me. Thanks!

**state.allStudents** is the array. And the **students** is the new object to replace that existing object in the array with same _id

```
state.allStudents = _.unionBy([students], state.allStudents, '_id');
```

Comment: can you add an example?

Comment: Why downvote? The question was clearly asked and he offered enough information to solve and he showed us what he trried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `.findIndex` and `.splice`

```
    let index = state.allStudents.findIndex(i => i._id === students._id);
    if (index != -1) {
        state.allStudents.splice(index, 1, students);
    }
```

Comment: I'm guessing that you are using vuex. If so, this has the added benefit of maintaining reactivity.